# Change text in Div using jQuery, MetaData and Map highlights

Tags: jquery-plugins, dictionary, metadata, highlight, onmouseover

I'm a newbie to jQuery and I have a map with a [highlight plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maphilight), when mouse over an area I want to change the text in a div with an ID and the text I will get it from the area attribute Alt="some text"

Here is the code that used for area loops, I'm pretty sure I can add a small function here but I couldn't figure it out.

```
//map 
clicks$(".tabs area").click(function(){

   //areas loop:
   $(".tabs area").each(function(){
       var d = $(this).data('maphilight') || {};
       if(d.alwaysOn == true){
         d.alwaysOn = false;  
       }
     });

   var data = $(this).data('maphilight') || {};
   data.alwaysOn = true;
   $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');

   if ($(this).hasClass("current") == false)
   {
       var thisTarget = $(this).attr("href");                          
       $(this).parents(".tabs").find('area.current').removeClass('current');
       $(this).addClass('current');  
       $(this).parents(".tabs").nextAll(".tab-content").children(":visible").fadeOut(1, function() {
           $(thisTarget).fadeIn("fast");
       });

   }
   return false; 
});
```

Any help or suggestions on how I can get this done would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the highlights plugin, but I think you just wanna add a mouseover event to each area like so (you would place this before/after your .click declaration):

```
$(".tabs area").mouseover(function() {
        var alt_text = $(this).attr('alt');
        $("#YOUR_TEXT_DIV_ID").html(alt_text);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        //do something on mouseout
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and let you know.